# CSS3 Animation to hoverstate and back

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I need an element that initially has no animation, then animates to a different state on hover (one time, no loop) and after the hover is gone it should animate back to its original state.

Basically just like you would do it with a `:hover` style and a `transition`.

Is there a way to achieve that with a CSS3 animation?

This is my current usecase: http://jsfiddle.net/yjD73/11/

On hover an element fades from opacity: 0 to opacity: 1 and back.
This is what i think is not possible with transitions.

EDIT: As requested here the exact code from jsfiddle

a `div` with four images

```
<div class="zoombox">
    <img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&size=300x300&maptype=hybrid&zoom=4&center=51.561998,-1.605100">
    <img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&size=300x300&maptype=hybrid&zoom=7&center=51.561998,-1.605100">
    <img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&size=300x300&maptype=hybrid&zoom=12&center=51.561998,-1.605100">
    <img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&size=300x300&maptype=hybrid&zoom=16&center=51.562606,-1.605100">
</div>
```

images stacked onto each other and simple css animations on hover

```
.zoombox {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px;
  float: left;
}

/* initial state */
.zoombox img:not(:first-child) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

/* On hover in */
.zoombox:hover img:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation: first-in 400ms 0ms 1 normal ease-in both;
}

.zoombox:hover img:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation: middle-in 1600ms 0ms 1 linear both;
}

.zoombox:hover img:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation: middle-in 1600ms 1200ms 1 linear both;
}

.zoombox:hover img:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-animation: last-in 400ms 2400ms 1 linear both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes first-in {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes middle-in {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25%, 75% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes last-in {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use w3schools. It's widely inaccurate at places. I suggest MDN instead.

Comment: Give us a jsfiddle or something to work with so we can show you the proper code and get you a better result, otherwise I would just say to use the css3 transitions but you haven't told us what this is for say I am not the judge of it can be done in a transition.

Comment: Thanks for your offer @Ilan Biala, i updated the question so it shows my current usecase. If this is possible with pure transition i'm happy of course.

Comment: Transitions are exactly the usecase for something like this where it is just one state to another, a few things changing. Additionally, I don't know why but I can't see any jsfiddle code right now, so I have no idea what you did, but I will respond ASAP once I see the code.

Comment: @Ilan Biala jsfiddle link is in the question, the problem i see with transitions is that you can only transition from states A->B and not A->B->C or A->B->A. If you can recreate my example using transitions i'm wrong

Comment: I don't see all of your code, you will have to post it here too.

Comment: @Ilan Biala i added the code from jsfiddle

Comment: your static maps urls give me an invalid request, double check to make sure they still work...

Comment: @Ilan Biala fixed image urls in both jsfiddle and question. You can also take four random equally sized images.

Answer (score 1):

Conic, I have created a JSFiddle that replicates most of what you want with css3 animations.

### [Here it is.](http://jsfiddle.net/nbatothemax/bttDX/13/)

The code that makes this all possible in CSS is:

```
@-webkit-keyframes changeImage {
  0%  {background: url("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&size=300x300&maptype=hybrid&zoom=4&center=51.561998,-1.605100");}
  33%  {background: url("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&size=300x300&maptype=hybrid&zoom=7&center=51.561998,-1.605100");}
  67%  {background: url("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&size=300x300&maptype=hybrid&zoom=12&center=51.561998,-1.605100");}
  100% {background: url("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&size=300x300&maptype=hybrid&zoom=16&center=51.562606,-1.605100");}
}
```

Right now the jsfiddle is having the image run through the animation on hover and return to the original image. Let me know if you need any over things to happen and by the way, this won't work on any touch devices as a result of a lack of hover state possibilities.

Comment: The problem with your solution is that you only change the background and don't fade-in / grow-to-original-size the image while appearing and fade-out / oversize the image while disappearing. Your transition is lacking the tricky part of my animation.

Comment: the tricky part of your animation is possible with your code, mine is less code, if you want to have that little magnifying effect which is kind of pointless, then just use your code...I don't see what's wrong with it.